# Am trying to use client.js for trello authentication. Irrespective of url i use, am getting invalid return_url

Tags: javascript, trello

To get the token for trello integration with my web-app, am using the client.js. however when i call Trello.authorize(opts); it is returning "invaid return_url" irrespective of the url am passing. if i just simply call the url of trello, it takes me to approve page where the token is there but i want to capture that in script and store. Pls help.

have tried by directly calling the /authorize url and by using the Trello.authorize method in client.js

```
var opts = {
    'type'          :   'popup',
    'name'          :   'My App',
    'persist'       :   true,
    'interactive'   :   true,
    'scope'         :   { read: true, write: true, account: true },
    'expiration'    :   'never',
    'success'       :   function() {
                            //console.log("this.Authenticate success");
                        },
    'error'         :   function () {
                            //console.log("this.Authenticate failed");

                        },
    return_url: "https://{HOST_NAME}/trello1.do",
};Trello.authorize(opts);
```

Comment: It worked. The Trello documentation was not clear about the origin URl. When i changed it, it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I find this works for me:

```
var authenticationSuccess = function() {
  const token = Trello.token();
  // you can save your token in here
};

Trello.authorize({
    type: "popup",
    name: "Power-up name",
    expiration: "never",
    success: authenticationSuccess,
    error: () => {},
});
```

I'm not passing in a return URL, but once you press the authenticate button on the pop-up, it closes, which works for my use case.